# How to make a screen appear moving right side after splash screen in android cocos2d

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

i am developing a game App using cocos2d android. After loading screen i have a menu screen and two more screen i need to get some effect like After the splash screen when it moves to next screen i need something like rotating or moving towards right/left How can i do this can any one suggest me? How to get this effect when moving from one screen to next  activity? Thank you in advance and your answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hi I hope this help you. In this code i used splash screen moves to left and next screen comes form right side of the screen*

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(CCSlideInRTransition.transition(1, MainMenuScreen.sence()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my application using flip animation 
 you can use **flip left in and flip right in**, **fade in or fade out**   animation in the activity.
use  `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout);`before the activity start

Answer (score 0):

Got solution!!! just use the below code

CCDirector.sharedDirector().pushScene(CCSlideInTTransition.transition(1, scene));